# HTML 5 brush color won't change value

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

So I have this really simple HTML that has a canvas, and a few buttons. When I click the green button, or yellow. I would like it to change my brush's stroke color. When I click the button nothing happens. The color stays the same.

Here's my script and HTML: JS + JQuery 1.7.2

```js
var canvas;

$(function () {
canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.backgroundColor = '#efefef';
canvas.isDrawingMode= 1;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = e.target.value;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 1;
canvas.renderAll();
document.getElementById('colorpicker').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
console.log(e.target.value);
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = e.target.value;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" class="canvas"></canvas>
<!--
<select name="colors" id="colorpick">
<option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
<option value="#000000">Black</option>
<option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
</select>
-->

<div id= "colorpicker">
<button id= "yellow" value= "FFFF00">yellow</button>
<button id= "black" value= "000000">black</button>
<button id= "green" value = "#00ff00">green</button>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Link. Works properly. I guess because of the JQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/6zrm8tun/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this buddy - need to tidy a few things up but I got this working in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nfbe076k/

```js
var canvas;
var yellow = document.getElementById('yellow');
var black = document.getElementById('black');
var green = document.getElementById('green');
$(function () {
    canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    canvas.backgroundColor = '#efefef';
    canvas.isDrawingMode= 1;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'green';
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 1;
    canvas.renderAll();

yellow.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#' + this.value;
    });
  black.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#' + this.value;
  });
    green.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#' + this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="colorpicker">
  <button id="yellow" value="FFFF00">yellow</button>
  <button id="black" value="000000">black</button>
  <button id="green" value="00ff00">green</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 things wrong with your code:

1. You're referencing `e` before it exists which is an exception, set that to a default e.g. `canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'green'`
2. You're assigning the colour but it doesn't start with a hash, change to: `<button id="yellow" value="#FFFF00">` etc

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/ph5cv6oa/2/